# The name of those side panels on hotel beds

Tags: furniture

In most (American) hotels that I've been to, I couldn't accidentally lose something under the bed, because the space between the floor and the frame is protected by boards or panels.

I'd like to get a set of those for home. Does anyone know what they're called? Can they be bought alone, or do they only come as part of the bed frame?

EDIT: In response to the first two answers: the ones I saw are not decorative; in fact, they're recessed to the point that you might never see them unless you bend down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a "plinth".

Usually the ones in hotels are not covering the bed or attached to the bed, they ARE the bed, ie there's just a wooden box upon which the mattress rests.

If you can buy one of these separately to wrap around an existing bed frame, I don't think so, but it would probably cost at least as much as a low-end bed designed this way, and would not look as good or fit as nicely in the space.

Edit: to contrast with the other answer showing good add-on ways to do it, the ones in hotels are not like Divan beds, they are like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a good option for a box & mattress type bed. The weight will provide a good seal with the floor to prevent dust etc... but for the inevitable cleaning you have to lift the box & mattress which is a pain. The skirting in the "other" add-on answer won't seal as well, but access for cleaning is likely easier. Something for the OP to consider.

Comment: I think you're right, although the ones I've found online are usually called a "bed base'.  (I get different, decorative items when I search for "plinth".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a special name for this type of bed frame, but it is usually purchased as a full set of bedding (bed frame + box spring + mattress).

Edit: Divan Bed (per Snow's comment)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here in the UK, these are called "divan beds".  Not sure if there's an equivalent term in the USA.

Comment: Another option in the US is often called a pedestal bed. This is a wooden bed frame that includes drawers under the bed for additional storage.

Comment: The pedestal bed with drawers is called a captains bed frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a **"bed skirt"** with a harder material behind the fabric.

[image]

Image https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/346917977531570474/

Or purchase a **"bed wrap"**, which is a stiffened fabric that is wrapped around the bed and gripped to the bed with straps at the bed's corners between the frame and mattress

[image]

Image https://standardtextilehome.com/products/circa-bed-wrap